# Continuous extension preserving modulus of continuity

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, metric-spaces, extension

Let $X$ be a (non-empty) compact subset of $D(0,M):=\left\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n:\, \|x\|\leq M\right\}$, and let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be uniformly continuous; for some metric space $Y$.  Are there any known result guaranteeing that $f$ can be extended to a uniformly continuous function $F:D(0,M)\rightarrow Y$ such that the modulus of continuity of $f$ is (point-wise) greater-than or equal to the modulus of continuity of $F$?

Comment: If $X$ is the sphere, then possibility of extension means that $n-1$-th homotopy group of $Y$ vanish. Also, it doesn't say in the body of the question that modulus of continuity has to be preserved (as you mentioned in the title). Could you please clarify?

Comment: I added the requested clarification.  However, I don't see the homotopic argument.

Comment: one of the definition of having vanishing $n-1$-th homotopy group is precisely existence of extension of any continuous map $f:S^{n-1}\to Y$ to $F:D_{n}\to Y$

Comment: Oh ya?  This is interesting.  Would you happen to have a reference I could look in to?

Comment: See for example Hatcher - Algebraic topology, chapter on homotopy groups

Comment: @erz I just noticed; this definition odes not guarantee that the extension has same modulus of continuity

Comment: I did not claim it does. It's just a necessary condition